# flutter upload progress bar while uploading the video

Tags: flutter, dart, http, upload, progress-bar

i want to have a circular upload progress bar when the video is being uploaded to the server i am using file picker to get the video from the internal storage my function looks like this

```
 _getGallery() async {
    FilePickerResult? result =
        await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(type: FileType.video);
    print('result : $result');
    if (result != null) {
      if (!checkConnection()) {
        return;
      }
      if (subjectController.text == '') {
        warningSnackBar(context, 'Please enter the subject');
        return;
      }
      setState(() {
        videoFile = File(result.files.single.path.toString());
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (BuildContext builder) => VideoWIllSaveScreen(
                videoFile: videoFile,
                connection_id: connectionID,
                name: connectionName,
                deliver_type: deliver_type,
                subject: subjectController.text,
                videoUrl: ''),
          ),
        );
      });
    } else {
      customSnackBar('Failed to load video', 'Error');
    }
  }
```

I tried to use a bool = isloading and set it false then when video is being uploaded set state as true and make the progress bar apprear

Comment: You can use CircularProgressIndicator or LinearProgressIndicator to show the progress.
You can also use package like https://pub.dev/packages/percent_indicator

Comment: thanks can you just tell me how to make it appear only for the time when the file is being getting uploaded

Comment: set a flag, when upload start set isUploading to true and when it completed 100% update isUploading to flase.
Show Progress Widget according to the flag. If the flag is true show the progress and when it updates to false hide your progress.